# Translation of a point on a circle

Tags: math, geometry

I am given a circle with radius R and its centre in the point (0,0) and a point P(x,y), situated on the circle ( x*x+y*y=R*R). I have to move the point P in a clockwise direction, on the circle, with an angle Z, and find the coordinates of the new point. Is there any mathematical formula for doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: From my cursory reading, just use [Polar Coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinates#Circle)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using polar co-ordinates, you can derive the following.

Initially assume (x, y) in cartesian is (r, t) in polar co-ordinates in the following way

```
x = r * cos(t)
y = r * sin(t)
```

Now let (x', y') be new points after rotating an angle a (anti-clockwise)

```
x' = r * cos(t + a)
y' = r * sin(t + a)
```

Expanding them out, you can get the following

```
x' = r * cos (t) * cos (a) - r * sin (t) * sin (a) 
y' = r * sin (t) * cos (a) + r * cos (t) * sin (a)

x' = x * cos (a) - y * sin (a)
y' = x * sin (a) + y * cos (a)
```

Now substitute a = -theta (since you mentioned theta in clock wise direction), you will get the new points.

Answer (score 1):

Use Polar Coordinates for this use this class or infer the trigonometry:

Method of Interest:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns polar coordinate converted to 2-d cartesian coordinates.
    /// Coordinates are relative to 0,0 of the angle base vertex
    /// </summary>
    public Point Point
    {
      get
      {
        int x = (int)(m_R * Math.Cos(m_Theta));
        int y = (int)(m_R * Math.Sin(m_Theta));
        return new Point(x, y);
      }
    }
```

Whole Class:

```
  /* NFX by ITAdapter
   * Originated: 2006.01
   * Revision: NFX 0.2  2009.02.10
   */
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Text;

  namespace NFX.Geometry
  {

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a point with polar coordinates
    /// </summary>
    public struct PolarPoint
    {

      #region .ctor

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes polar coordinates
        /// </summary>
        public PolarPoint(double r, double theta)
        {
          m_R = r;
          m_Theta = 0;
          Theta = theta;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes polar coordinates from 2-d cartesian coordinates
        /// </summary>
        public PolarPoint(Point center, Point point)
        {
          this = CartesianUtils.PointToPolarPoint(center, point);
        }
      #endregion

      #region Private Fields 
        private double m_R;
        private double m_Theta;

      #endregion


      #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// R coordinate component which is coordinate distance from point of coordinates origin
        /// </summary>
        public double R
        {
          get { return m_R; }
          set { m_R = value; }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Angular azimuth coordinate component. An angle must be between 0 and 2Pi.
        /// Note: Due to screen Y coordinate going from top to bottom (in usual orientation)
        ///  Theta angle may be reversed, that is - be positive in the lower half coordinate plane.
        /// Please refer to:
        ///  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinates
        /// </summary>
        public double Theta
        {
          get { return m_Theta; }
          set
          {
            if ((value < 0) || (value > Math.PI * 2))
              throw new NFXException("Invalid polar coordinates angle");
            m_Theta = value;
          }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns polar coordinate converted to 2-d cartesian coordinates.
        /// Coordinates are relative to 0,0 of the angle base vertex
        /// </summary>
        public Point Point
        {
          get
          {
            int x = (int)(m_R * Math.Cos(m_Theta));
            int y = (int)(m_R * Math.Sin(m_Theta));
            return new Point(x, y);
          }
        }
      #endregion



      #region Operators  
        public static bool operator ==(PolarPoint left, PolarPoint right)
        {
          return (left.m_R == right.m_R) && (left.m_Theta == right.m_Theta);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(PolarPoint left, PolarPoint right)
        {
          return (left.m_R != right.m_R) || (left.m_Theta != right.m_Theta);
        }
      #endregion


      #region Object overrides
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
          if (obj is PolarPoint)
           return this==((PolarPoint)obj);
          else
           return false; 
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
          return m_R.GetHashCode() + m_Theta.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
          return string.Format("Distance: {0}; Angle: {1} rad.", m_R, m_Theta);
        }


      #endregion

    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the cartesian to polar formulae:

> x = r*cos(theta)
>
> y = r*sin(theta)

Use radians and solve for both the originating point and destination point (you are missing theta for originating point, and you have the delta theta for the destination point).

Then convert back to cartesian:

> r^2 = x^2 + y^2
>
> r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
>
> theta = arctan(y/x)

A great reference can be found at http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarCoordinates.aspx